# cast string to date or int in dataframe spark 1.6 java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, casting, group-by

how to cast string to date or int in dataframe spark 1.6.
I want to group my data for period 1/10/100 years, 
dataFrame have colomn "dt" - string 
coding for java
example:

[image]

how can i do this?

Comment: Please do not post links to screenshots on external website providers. Use the in-built provider instead. Also consider not posting screenshots at all if it's not 100% necessary as links tend to not be available forever and members using screen readers are not able to have a look at them.

Comment: ok, i understand

Comment: I could help with Spark 2.x, 1.6 is a little old now ;)... did you look at the static functions?

Comment: ammm, not see( or no understanding(

Answer (score 0):

```
DataFrame dataFrame = sqlContext.read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("header", "true")
            .load(filePath.getAbsolutePath());


    DataFrame withDate = dataFrame.withColumn("date",col("dt").cast("date"));

    withDate.withColumn(
            "year",
            year(col("date"))
    ).withColumn(
            "month",
            month(col("date"))
    ).withColumn(
            "day",
            dayofmonth(col("date"))
    ).show();
```

or

```
DataFrame inputFrame = sqlContext.read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("header", "true")
            .load(filePath.getAbsolutePath());


    DataFrame with_data_frame = inputFrame
            .withColumn(
                    "date", col("dt").cast("date"))
            .withColumn(
                    "year",year(col("date"))
            );
    with_data_frame.show();
```

perfect)